# Why can a method be called on another method?

Tags: java, oop, object, methods

```
NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();
```

I am new to JAVA. Can anyone be kind enough to explain the structure of the above statement?

I understand that a method of an instance can be accessed in the following way:

```
objectName.methodName();
```

In the above statement, there are three method names associated with one object name. How does this work?

Comment: What type is `eElement`?

Comment: Use an IDE and read through the associated Javadoc. 3 method names are not associated with one object name, the methods are associated with the objects returned by other methods.

Comment: If that is a bad question, why are there so many good answers? :) @Downvoters: Please let rohit know what he/she can improve.

Comment: @Mulmoth If you look at the edit history it should be clear that this question is a mess.

Comment: Alright. I understand its a mess but can someone please answer my question?

Comment: @Mark this doesn't make helpful comments unneccessary. You may downvote it (although I think it's better to edit it if possible), but please tell why.

Comment: @Mulmoth I didn't downvote, I voted to close, because the original question was unintelligble, it also doesn't help that the last edit by the OP changed it into a different question.

Comment: @Mulmoth,Mark Apologies for not following the protocol. I agree that the question has turned into a mess and it needs to be closed but der were some very good answers which may be useful to some people. So either close the question or i'l revert the edit to the original post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `eElement.getElementsByTagName` will return an object
- on that object you then call `.item(0)` which will return another object
- on that last object you call `.getChildNodes()`

Indeed, a method can be called by doing `object.method()`, but if you have multiple calls like this, you can chain them like in your example.

As long as you don't overdo it, this can result in a more readable code, it keeps it compact.

Comment: Not so much nested as chained, I would suggest

Comment: @SoboLAN Thanks a lot. That was very comprehensive.

Answer (score 4):

The call to `eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag)` returns some object. After that, `item(0)` is called on this object. And so on. In other words, the statement above is equivalent to

```
SomeObject so = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag);
OtherObject oo = so.item(0);
NodeList nlList = oo.getChildNodes();
```

This technique is called [*method chaining*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), and it can be very useful - if not overdone - in making the code more concise and readable.

A special form of it - widely used in some frameworks, e.g. Hibernate - is chaining method calls on the same object, e.g.

```
SomeObject o = new SomeObject().setFoo(1).setBar("boo").setBaz(42);
```

This is arguably more compact than

```
SomeObject o = new SomeObject();
o.setFoo(1);
o.setBar("boo");
o.setBaz(42);
```

Which you definitely need if you don't have a constructor with the needed parameters. But even if such a constructor is available, one might argue that

```
SomeObject o = new SomeObject(1, "boo", 42);
```

is less readable than the method chaining idiom. Alas, Java (unlike C#) has no named parameters in method calls.

Comment: @SoboLAN, indeed, I just didn't want to throw too much new stuff on the OP at once :-)

Answer (score 3):

Each method works on the return value of the previous statement e.g.

```
   obj.getA().getB().getC();
```

means that you call `getA()` on obj. That returns an object A, and then you call `getB()` on *the resultant object A* - not the original `obj`.

It's similar to

```
   temp1 = obj.getA();
   temp2 = temp1.getB();
   temp3 = temp2.getC();
```

but without the temporary variables.

The downside is that it's more difficult to debug since you don't have the intermediate variables, and perhaps more fragile (if, for example `getA()` returns null then *the whole statement blows up* and you can't easily tell where, since the stacktrace contains the line number alone).

Answer (score 2):

The above statement executes in the following steps:

1) In the variable eElement which is of type Element - get all tags with the name of sTag. This method returns a NodeList

2) In the returned NodeList - get the first item (0) out of the list. This returns a Node.

3) On the returned Node - get all of its child nodes, which returns a NodeList and assigns it to nlList.

Where a method returns an object, you can keep calling methods on the returned objects however deep you want to go. As long as the resulting method returns an object of the type you are trying to assign to.

Answer (score 1):

1. all nodes with a name  "sTag" are retrieved from eElement

   eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag)
2. from them, the first one is selected

   eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
3. all the children from that first node are now in nlList

   NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks for the explanation. I have a follow up query on this. What will be in nlList, if there are no ChildNodes??

Comment: Hi, according to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html), it's going to be an empty nodeList

Answer (score 0):

if `objectName.methodName()` returns an object, then you can call a method on that object, e.g. `objectName.methodName().anotherMethod()`. It is just a simple chaining of method calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
objectName.methodName();
```

may also return an object reference (as long as its return type is not 'void') so really it is:

```
objectRef = objectName.methodName();
```

The second method call is on the object returned by the first. So in your example

```
eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();
```

an object is returned by getElementsByTagName(sTag) and item(0) is called on that. The object returned by that second method call, then has getChildNodes() called on that.